# python manage.py collectstatic on Aws Elasticbeanstalk ends with error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I try to setup Django website on AWS EB. I have running environment and S3 Bucket. I created superuser for my project and migrated it to postgresql database. The problem is I cannot run collectstatic. This is error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/app/current/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/var/app/current/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 338, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 248, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/storages/backends/s3.py", line 514, in exists
    self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 946, in _make_api_call
    api_params = self._emit_api_params(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1072, in _emit_api_params
    self.meta.events.emit(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 282, in validate_bucket_name
    if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):
```

Where should I look for source of my issue?

I checked all settings, including IAM Roles, networking rules and all seems to be correct